# Can a single application can be server and the client and query itself

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

Can a single program be at the same time a server, a client and query itself over TCP (and ssl)?
I'm working on a project where I need a configuration like that.
I need to use the Boost Asio lib and OpenSSL.

Comment: Yes, you can put both server and client code in the same binary. But there's no reason to use TCP and SSL. You can just use an anonymous socketpair.

Comment: I don't see how this question is "too broad" its a simple yes/no answer and the answer is yes. I can see this being relevant in some applications like  P2P networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a TCP server and client within the same program for communication.

But it's not recommended:

1. This will alert the Windows firewall even with default settings, because of the TCP server
2. This makes your application more prone to eavesdropping.
3. The performance will never be as good + see #4:
4. Why would you communicate using TCP within your own application instead of using function parameters? It's like talking to yourself when shopping for groceries.

Comment: It's like driving the bread to the grocery store and back before making a sandwich :)

Comment: For #4, I have seen some multiplayer games use this approach.  If the application protocol is processed at a discrete time steps, then the overhead of TCP may have no effect.  For these particular cases, one could argue that introducing branching logic creates technical debt at little gain.